# How do I search for a certain character in a text file and say what row and column its in

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

```
def find_csv(filename, keyvalue):
    with open(filename, "r") as csv_file:
        file_name = csv_file
        keyvalue = input("please enter what you would like to find in the file: ")
        file = file_name.read()
        file = file.strip(",")



xxx = input("please enter the file: ")
print(find_csv(xxx, ""))
```

Comment: Iterate over lines, then through lines...

Comment: Try using **Regular Expressions**

Comment: @Nivedh: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems. " - Jamie Zawinski

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have a very simple csv (simple.csv):

```
bla,blub,bleb
helo,hallo,bye
wow,wuw,wiw
```

I modified your code to use the standard python csv library:

```
import csv

def find_csv(filename, keyvalue):
    with open(filename, "r", newline='') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
        for row_idx, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
            for col_idx, col in enumerate(row):
                if keyvalue in col:
                    return row_idx, col_idx


print(find_csv("simple.csv", "wuw"))
```

The result of this snippet is: `(2, 1)` (indices start at 0, but you can simply add 1 if you like).

I did not perform any exception handling etc. to keep the example short and simple. Please don't use as is ;)

I hope this helps. If not please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

There is all kinds of confusion going on with your example.  You have used some quite advanced constructs like with for instance.  When you are starting to learn programming I would definitely try using baby steps. Here is some code that does what you want:

```
def find_csv(filename, string_to_find):
    with open(filename, "r") as csv_file:
        line = 0
        for text in csv_file.readlines():    
            line += 1
            char = text.find(string_to_find)
            if char >= 0:
                return 'string found at line %s, character %s'%(line, char)
    return "string not found"

file_to_look_in = "temp.py"
print(find_csv(file_to_look_in, "find_csv"))
```

In your code you have keyvalue come in as an input but never use it.  Instead you ask for the input inside the function.  This is bad practice. You also reassign csv_file to file_name which is unnecessary. Also 'file_name' is close to 'filename' and can cause confusion. I would even question the name of the function since the name implies that you are finding a csv file not finding something in a csv file.  Since this function could find something in any file I would make the name more generic. The fact that you probably wrote it to find a particular value within a CSV file has nothing to do with the functioning of the code.  Good naming makes the code not only more readable but also more writable since it clarifies in your mind what kind of value the variable is holding. I hope this helps you.